# How to capitalize characters in the middle of a word using regex

Tags: regex

For example, johnathan to johNAThan

Comment: What logic dictates its NAT that is capitalized?

Comment: Also what programming language is this in?

Comment: do you mean literally the most middle?  like cat to cAt  and moon to mOOn and would tests become tESTs or teSts?  Need a logical pattern to work with.

Comment: @BillGates it will take you many years to be a billionaire on SO :P

Comment: @sniperd something like if the word = 7 characters then letter 3 4, if 8 characters then 3 4 5, some pattern that capitalizes the middle letters, the longer the word, i dont know if it can be done using regex

Comment: I don't think this can solely be done with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this only in regex, but you can do something like this in perl.

```
cat a|perl -lane ' if( length($_) == 7) { s/(..)(..)(.*)/\1\U\2\E\3/; print}   if( length($_) > 7) { s/(..)(...)(.*)/\1\U\2\E\3/; print} '
```